# How new keyword works in derive class

Tags: c#, new-operator, shadowing

I am having some confusion with the new keyword,things work fine when I am using virtual and override , but a bit different with new(I think I am missing something)

```
 class A
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in A");
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in B");
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.Test(); //I am in B
        A a = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType()); // Type-B
        a.Test(); //I am in B
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Now with new

```
class A
{
    public  void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in A");
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public new void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in B");
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.Test(); //I am in B
        A a = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType()); //B
        a.Test(); // I am in A ? why?
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

as per MSDN When the new keyword is used, the new class members are called instead of the base class members that have been replaced. Those base class members are called hidden members, also the GetType() is Showing type as B.
So where I am going wrong, seems its a silly mistake :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hide a base-class method using the `new` keyword, the call is resolved by the compiler, not at runtime.

Therefore, when you write `a.Test`, the compiler emits a call to the `Test` method on the `A` class.  Even though the `a` variable happens to refer to a `B` instance, the compiler doesn't care, and it still calls the version on `A`.

When you call a virtual method, the compiler emits a `callvirt` instruction that tells the runtime to find the correct method to call based on the actual type of the instance.  The runtime is aware that the instance is actually of type `B`, and will see that `B` overrides the method and call the overridden version.

Comment: That means this is Compile time vs Runtime..I got your point , thnx.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Jon Skeet's descriptio](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#override.new)n of the `new` keyword usage. Because a is cast as A, you are calling A's method, which cannot be overridden. B just happens to have a method with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, once you create additional classes which derive from either `A` or `B`, you'll find that calling `base.Test()` will call `A`'s version for those classes which `override` rather than `new` and those which derive from `B` will have `B`'s version called but NOT `A`'s.

Answer (score 0):

> The "new" means the method is "new" and not an "override". Therefore, if you call a method by that name from the base, it hasn't been overriden so the derived won't be called.